# I got error in mongodb shell while redeclaration

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-shell

Any faced this issue in mongodbshell

```
let martian = db.movieDetails.find({"title":"The Martian"})
let martian = db.movieDetails.find({"title":"The Martian"})
2020-04-20T12:54:11.297+0400 E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: SyntaxError: redeclaration of let martian :
@(shell):1:1
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you already declared `martian`, you don't need `let` in the second statement, that's why it's complaining. I think you just need to overwrite the variable content. Try:

```js
let martian = db.movieDetails.find({"title":"The Martian"})
martian = db.movieDetails.find({"title":"The Martian"})
```